# ExtJS: Alter Store pageSize

Tags: extjs, pagination, store, extjs4.2

Say I have a store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyTestStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.MyTestStore',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MyTestModel'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyTestModel',
        remoteFilter: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        storeId: 'MyTestStore',
        buffered: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        listeners: {
            load: {
                fn: me.onStoreLoad,
                scope: me
            },
            beforeload: {
                fn: me.onStoreBeforeLoad,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
},

onStoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {

    console.log('load', records.length);
},

onStoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
    console.log('beforeload',operation);
}

});
```

As you can see initially I load it with pageSize:100 which is perfect for when I'm loading this store initially, but later on I want to be able to load all of it aka I want to be able to change the pageSize. I tried the following:

```
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').reload({params:{start:0, limit:50000}});
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').reload({start:0, limit:50000, page:1, addRecords:true});
```

But neither seemed to be working. I figured it was obviously cause the pageSize was still set to 100. So I went and updated the store on the fly:

```
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').lastPageSize = 50000;
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').pageSize = 50000;
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').pageMap.pageSize = 50000;
```

Now when I console.log(Ext.getStore('MyTestStore')) everything shows up properly, but I'm still getting only 100 records. I looked at the code returning from the server and I'm properly getting every record, but when the function 'onload' runs above the record count stays at 100. Is there anyway to change it and force it to alter it's own pagesize?

Edit (Additional Information):

So another weird part is that when I do the following:

```
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').reload({start:0, limit:50000, page:1, addRecords:true, callback : function(r, options, success) {
    console.log(r.length,success)
}});
```

I get back:

```
load 100
6362 true
```

in my console. The 1st line is from the 'onStoreLoad' function and the 2nd one is from my reload function. So obviously I'm getting back all my records, but somewhere most of them are being blocked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Ext.getStore('MyTestStore').reload({start:0, limit:50000});
Ext.apply(Ext.getStore('MyTestStore'), {pageSize: 50000});
```

'limit' & 'pageSize' should keep the value.

Answer (score 0):

change the pageSize from the store configuration. You can call nextPage() to next page.

If you want to change number records for each page, you can use loadPage with pagenumber and options. See [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store). You can use same options which you used in your example.

Try this and let me know.